# Mongo nested fields populating issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
var buyerSchema = new Schema({
   cart: [{
       id: {
           type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: "product"
       },
       number: Number
    }],
    personName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    image: { type: String, required: false, trim: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
})
```

**How can i populate the Id field**

```
buyerMdl.findByToken(buyer['token']).populate({path: 'cart', populate: {path : 'id', model : 'product'}})
```

this particular command is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure your `findByToken` method returns an instance of find so that you can use `.populate()` in the chain.

The problem is that you're trying to populate a property which is not referenced. So instead of populating `card` and then `id`s in it, you should directly populate `cart.id`s.

This should work:

```
buyerMdl
    .findByToken(buyer['token'])
    .populate({
       path: 'cart.id',
       model: 'product'
     });
```

Comment: @MayankNauriyal Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `id` is inside card array... So you should use with dot notation to populate `id`

```
buyerMdl.findByToken(buyer['token']).populate({ path: 'cart.id' })
```